# Кодировка переменных окружения

Tags: python, кодировка, utf-8, python-2.x

Хочу передать POST запросом на сервер GAE строку с именем пользователя системы

```
values = dict(
    userName = os.environ.get("USERNAME"),
    compName = os.environ.get("COMPUTERNAME") 
)
data = urlencode(values)
req = urllib2.Request(url, data)
urllib2.urlopen(req)
```

Если имя пользователя не латиницей, на стороне сервера получаю:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xc0 in position 0: invalid start byte
```

Comment: Так где бросется исключение, в приведенном коде или нет?

Comment: Да как то я не уточнил.

Исключение на сервера GAE webapp2 
self.request.get("userName")

Comment: А что там делается со значением self.request.get("userName"), сам метод Request.get() вроде как не должен такое исключение бросать.

Comment: Там только присвоение переменной

userName = ...

Comment: Нет ошибки если я получаю так, надо пребразовывать потом

repr(os.environ.get(...))

Comment: А что если передать значение `os.environ.get("USERNAME").encode("utf-8")`?

Comment: userName = os.environ.get("USERNAME").encode("utf-8"),
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc0 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: `os.environ.get("USERNAME").encode("utf-8")` - ошибочный код, так как переменные среды не преобразуются в объект unicode автоматически, а содержат "сырые" строки, кодировка которых зависит от ОС

Comment: Значит, нужно задекодить из исходной кодировки системы и закодить в utf-8. )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для определения кодировки каких-либо данных лично я частенько применяю такой способ: сдампить проблемные данные в текстовый файл, а потом файл открыть  в любимом браузере и пощёлкать по наиболее вероятным вариантам кодировок, а когда увидишь не кракозябры, а что-либо читабельное -- бинго!

Например, так это делается из командной строки в Linux:

```
$ python 
>>> open("test.txt", "w").write(os.environ['USERNAME'])
CTRL+D
$ chromium test.txt
```

Если у тебя ОС Windows, наиболее вероятными кодировками переменных среды будут CP1251, CP866, UTF-16. Найденную эмпирическим путём кодировку нужно использовать для преобразования "сырой" строки из среды в объект unicode:

```
>>> os.environ('USERNAME').decode('your_encoding')
```

Comment: Это я тоже проходил, штирлиц показывает Cp1251

  data = urlencode(values)
  File "C:\Python2\lib\urllib.py", line 1312, in urlencode
    v = quote_plus(str(v))
  UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in   position 0-8: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: А ну все нормально, вроде работает как надо:
os.environ.get("USERNAME").decode("cp1251").encode("utf-8"),

Answer (score -1):

Файл сохраните в кодировке utf-8, а так же в начале файла напишите:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

Comment: Это есть и там и там

Comment: Этот служебный комментарий всего лишь позволяет использовать в исходном тексте литералы в кодировке отличной от Latin-1, и никак не влияет на интерпретацию строковых объектов.